# How does my crystal PCB layout look?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, layout, crystal, high-speed

Please suggest if the layout is fine:

1. it is 25MHz 3225 crystal.
2. I maintained short traced for XIN and XOUT.
3. I maintained a guard ring around the crystal.
4. I have grounding in layer just below.
5. the dotted shape is also ground.

[image]

Comment: it looks good to me, 25Mhz is pretty slow really so layout is not critical.  they write stuff in the datasheet so you don't put the crystal on the other end of the PCB, or make great big loops with the wires /

Comment: @Jasen That's an answer to the question, not a comment, so it should be posted as an answer so it can be up or downvoted, edited, commented on, and most important: accepted as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks good. 25 MHz is not amazingly fast, you can probably get away without the ring.

As a rule of thumb, things start to get a little scary above 100 MHz, a 25 MHz crystal is "easy".